# Unable to install MySQL after accidentally installing mariadb

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-14.04, apt, mysql5

I have tried a complete removal of everything (I even backed up and removed databases) each install comes with a different error; either my.cnf has `MARIA DB` at the top or dpkg has a config issue (`[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'log_slow_verbosity=query_plan'`).

When I run the mysql install I am hit with `Could not connect to MYSQL or root password already set`

Attempting to reinstall mysql server 5.5 on ubuntu 14 server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

> Use sudo apt-get purge  instead, to remove config files as
>   well.

https://askubuntu.com/posts/147281/edit

Comment: I purged, removed any file containing maria or mysql I could think of then removed the downloaded packages. Working now